# Python - Extracting text in a string between two other specific characters?

Tags: python, regex, zapier

I have various strings of text that have a user's name, their business name and phone number and they are all similar to the following:

```
FirstName LastName (Some Business Name / phoneNumber)
FirstName LastName (Business Name / phoneNumber)
FirstName LastName (BusinessName / differentphoneNumber)
FirstName LastName (Short Name / somephoneNumber)
FirstName LastName (Very Long Business Name / otherphoneNumber)
```

Real world examples could look like this:

```
David Smith (Best Pool and Spa Supplies / 07438473784)
Bessy McCarthur Jone (Dog Supplies / 0438-343522)
```

I have used this code to extract the first name (as I needed this earlier) and it works well:

```
import re
details = re.findall(r'^[\w+]+', input_data['stripeDescription'])
return {
'firstName': details[0] if details else None\``
}
```

How can I go about finding the text between the open bracket "(" and the forward slash "/" to then retrieve the business name?

Answer (score 3):

This may not be a perfect solution but it works fine :)

```
s1='David Smith (Best Pool and Spa Supplies / 07438473784)'
sp1=s1.split('(')
sp2=sp1[1].split('/')
print(sp2)
```

output: ['Best Pool and Spa Supplies ', ' 07438473784)']

Comment: This worked perfectly. I tried to add my take on this code but it won't go in these comments.  So thank you for your help

Comment: @robster, please keep in mind that if the business name has `(` in it, this will not work.

Comment: true, i didn't think about error  handling, i just tried to give an idea how to solve main question :)

Comment: and this is why it can be useful to assess if a regex is the best solution :-).  although... one might to watch out for / or ( in the business name.  you can reverse the string to get at the / from the right.  or use sp1[-1] ?

Answer (score 1):

Use parentheses to group the pattern you want to match in the regex you use for `re.findall`:

```
s = '''David Smith (Best Pool and Spa Supplies / 07438473784)
Bessy McCarthur Jone (Dog Supplies / 0438-343522)'''
import re
print(re.findall(r'\(([^/]+?) */', s))
```

This outputs:

```
['Best Pool and Spa Supplies', 'Dog Supplies']
```

Comment: Regex melts my mind.  I'm trying to get better with it and I appreciate your reply.  I'll study that some more with the regex101 tool to see if I can make sense of it.  Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly robust, but will not handle a name with parentheses in it. i.e. it expects the first `(` to delimit past the name.  However, you might be able know something is wrong by noting that the business then has `\).*\(` in it.

```
data = """
David Smith (Best Pool and Spa Supplies / 07438473784)
David Smith2 (Best Pool/Spa Supplies / 07438473784)
Bessy McCarthur Jone (Dog Supplies / 0438-343522)
Bessy McCarthur Jone2 (Dog (and cat) Supplies / 0438-343522)
Bessy (Bess, fails) McCarthur Jone3 (Dog Supplies / 0438-343522)
"""

lines = [line.strip() for line in data.splitlines() if line.strip()]

for line in lines:
    name,rest = line.split("(",1)
    name = name.strip()
    phone = rest.rsplit("/")[1].replace(")","").strip()
    biz = rest.rsplit("/",1)[0].strip()
    print("\n "+line)
    print(" =>name:%s: phone:%s:biz:%s:" % (name, phone,biz))
```

output:

```
 David Smith (Best Pool and Spa Supplies / 07438473784)
 =>name:David Smith: phone:07438473784:biz:Best Pool and Spa Supplies:

 David Smith2 (Best Pool/Spa Supplies / 07438473784)
 =>name:David Smith2: phone:Spa Supplies:biz:Best Pool/Spa Supplies:

 Bessy McCarthur Jone (Dog Supplies / 0438-343522)
 =>name:Bessy McCarthur Jone: phone:0438-343522:biz:Dog Supplies:

 Bessy McCarthur Jone2 (Dog (and cat) Supplies / 0438-343522)
 =>name:Bessy McCarthur Jone2: phone:0438-343522:biz:Dog (and cat) Supplies:

 Bessy (Bess, fails) McCarthur Jone3 (Dog Supplies / 0438-343522)
 =>name:Bessy: phone:0438-343522:biz:Bess, fails) McCarthur Jone3 (Dog Supplies:
```